# GNU sort -R deterministic or not?

Tags: gnu

I was under the impression the GNU `sort -R` was a pseudo-random shuffler of lines, i.e. deterministic. However, every time I run it the lines are in a different order! Am I misunderstanding `sort -R`? Is there another deterministic shuffler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deterministic behavior, you need to provide `--random-source` argument

e.g. `cat ~/tmp/test1.txt | sort -R --random-source=/dev/zero`

The `--random-source` acts like a seed and can point to any file

The default `sort -R` is not deterministic, I've tested on `Ubuntu 14.04`